# Is there any Firefox or Chrome add-on to highlight search terms (and jump to them ?)

Tags: firefox, search, browser-addons, firefox-extensions

There is a cool feature of the Google Toolbar that I have been finding frustrating to live without (since the Google Toolbar is not supported anymore for Firefox, my main browser):

When you google, let's say "hotel paris", and visit a result page, 2 new buttons "hotel" and "paris" appear in the Google Toolbar and allow you to jump to all occurrences of these words in the page. The highlight button on its part highlights these search terms with different colors.

I have found a Firefox add-on that includes the latter "Highlight search terms" button. (Groowe search toolbar).

But I am still missing the most useful buttons ("paris" and "hotel"). By the way, even Chrome lacks this feature (AFAIK)...

**-> Is there any add-on (for Firefox, preferably) that provides this kind of "Jump to search term" button ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this frustration too, and found that [Googlebar Lite](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/googlebar-lite/?src=search) is a near-perfect replacement for the now-defunct Google toolbar.  It allows most of the functionality of the original Google toolbar, but it still works with current versions of Firefox.  The "marker" button for highlighting the search terms and the ability to click a search term in the bar to go right to it in the page both function perfectly in this add-on.

Comment: Just installed it, looks perfect :)

Comment: Googlebar Lite seems to have disappeared

Comment: @Nathan Yeah, it and all the other toolbars were disallowed in Firefox when they switched to their Quantum architecture a couple years ago. Unfortunately, short of installing an out-of-date version, there's no way to get them back from now on.

Answer (score 1):

[Google Quick Scroll](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/okanipcmceoeemlbjnmnbdibhgpbllgc) for Chrome does what you want to some extent. It highlights the search term, and clicking on icon moves you to the search term

Answer (score 1):

yes there is: [SearchWP](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/searchwp/)

"Jump-to-word buttons and highlighting for the search box content"

it converts the words you typed into the searchbar into highlighted 'buttons', click one and it jumps to the next occurrence of that word in the current page! It handles too many words to fit int he searchbar by putting a little menu at the side. It works beautifully.

Comment: SearchWP has seemed to disappear

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use ctrl-F? No add-on required.

Comment: This is not an answer but a comment. And it's pretty obvious why I don't want to Ctrl-F : why would I want to type a word twice ?

Comment: @Sebastien - No. I was suggesting you use ctrl-F but wondering why you didn't but I did miss the part where you were searching two words that were separated.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome extension [Search Terms Finder](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/search-terms-finder/nlngijlbkkbebjhdmapcjgplnademcne) is kind of a port of SearchWP to Chrome (I'm the author). It shows a drop-down of Google search keywords, which you can jump to or highlight.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read [How to recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/a/5330/213131) for **minimum required information** and suggestions on how to recommend software on Super User.  To keep your answer useful even if the provided link(s) breaks these details should be edited into your answer.

Answer (score 0):

After years of searching in vain, I finally found a replacement for SearchWP:

[Isear](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/isear/cihgmhbajkkbciealhbbfhbbnmgaekdj) by [intelfike](http://isear.intelfike.net/)

Works absolutely fantastic, you just have to make the jump-to-word buttons visible by clicking on the extension's icon. However, highlighting of the search terms on subsequently opened search result pages occurs even without this.

Please everyone, get in touch with the creator of this plugin and motivate him to further development and  maintenance of the plugin! A translation of the search options into other languages would also be helpful.